# Auto reverse to original color only on mouse leave

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, wpf-animation, coloranimation

I'm using WPF in .Net framework 4.
I created a button with background color X.
I created a style for the button that on IsMouseOver start ColorAnimation  that change the background color to Blue.

In case that the IsMouseOver is false(the mouse is no logner over the button) I want to restore the button background to color X.

Example code:

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Trigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetName="MyButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.Color"  To="Blue"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </Trigger.EnterActions>
</Trigger>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Write a trigger that listens for IsMouseOver value to be false?

Comment: I did it already. I this case i need to set the color that I want to set as rollback color. I want to automatically use the previous color before the change.

Comment: use RemoveStoryBoard

Answer (score 7):

You can specify `ExitActions` along with `EnterActions` and don't set the `To` property so that it falls back to original value -

```
<Trigger.ExitActions>
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
            <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5"
                Storyboard.TargetName="MyButton"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</Trigger.ExitActions>
```

Comment: I want to return the previous background color and I don't know what it is. I just want to rollback the change...   Have idea how?

Comment: Ya.... This was my first try... The AutoReverse start automatically after the animation finished and not as a result of IsMouseOver is false. Any idea?? Please?

Comment: You need to go with `ExitActions` then and simply don't set the `To` property. It will automatically fall back to original value.

Comment: You should edit your answer. AutoReverse doesn't work like this.

Comment: Not setting the "To" property works perfectly for me (using an Opacity DoubleAnimation)